# Ember bidirectional value bind to object property

Tags: ember.js, bind

I want to achieve a very simple thing with a contenteditable div. Let us take this simple example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div contenteditable>{{MyApp.president.fullName}}</div>
</script>
```

I want the MyApp.president.fullname's value to change when I edit the content of the div. Does Ember have a way to do that? Or I have to observe the changes of the div's content and set the property with Ember.set?

I need all this to build a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! Next time you might have the balls to even say something, not only downvote without any obvious reason.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Ember.TextField`, with which you can bind values both ways:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="MyApp.president.fullName"}}
```

Using a textfield, when you change `MyApp.president.fullName` will update the textfield. When you change the value of the textfield it will update `MyApp.president.fullName`.

If you want to be able to edit any element you can do it like this:

Template:

```
{{#if MyApp.isEditing}}
  {{view App.InlineTextField valueBinding="MyApp.president.name"}}
{{else}}
  {{#view App.TextView}}
    {{MyApp.president.name}}    
  {{/view}}
{{/if}}
```

Views:

```
  App.InlineTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    focusOut: function() {
      MyApp.set('isEditing', false);
    }
  });

  App.TextView = Ember.View.extend({
    doubleClick: function() {
      MyApp.set('isEditing', true);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I will try it, thx! Using a input element is not really optimal from my application's point of view. I need to have a contenteditable field there, due to editing it on the spot, right in the page -- it is styled, it looks exactly like it will on the published page.

Comment: Actually, I think that the Ember team should make the contenteditable wotk the same way as a text input, due to it being a common use on the web today.

Comment: Actually I developed such a feature (inline editing text) and I'm replacing the `div` with a `TextField` whenever the user is in editMode (I use a flag `isEditing` that is set to true on double clicking the text). This way you won't have to mess with bindings.

Comment: That is ok for smaller text. But think of a longer text, multirow, say a blog post, with images and formatting inside. Did you have these and still used the text field?

Comment: Updated my answer. For paragraphs or any other text you will use Ember.TextArea. Style the textfield/textarea to look **exactly** as the <div> element.

Comment: That is not going to work. If you have inline styling inserted by the execCommand then that is going to look like plain text in the textarea.

Comment: Are we talking about binding text? Because in the fiddle you want to bind html. Handlebars.js/Ember.js will not parse HTML code in template variables. For that you would look for a WYSIWYG editor. But I thought you asked how to bind bidirectional :)

Comment: I did, I am using that bidirectional binding in a WYSIWYG editor.